# How can I make k nearest neighbor queries fast on unit hypersphere?

Tags: nearest-neighbour

I have $m$ points $D = \{x_1, \dots, x_m\}$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. After some preprocessing / building up data structures for those points, I get $T$ queries $y_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $i=1, \dots, T$. Each query comes at a time and independently. The datastructures for the queries should not be modified by the past queries. After receiving an query $y_i$, the $k$ nearest neighbors

$$NN_k(y_i) \subset D \text{ with } |NN_k(y_i)| = k \text{ and }$$ 
$$\forall x_a \in NN_k(y_i) \forall x_b \in D \setminus NN_k(y_i) : \|x_a - y_j\|_2 \leq \|x_b - y_j\|_2$$

All points $x_i$ and all queries $y_j$ are on the unit hypersphere, so $\|x_i\|_2 = \|y_i\|_2 = 1$.

How do I process those queries fast?

### Limits

To get a feeling for what matters, here are some orders of magnitude:

- $100 \leq n \leq 1000$: Dimension of points
- $m \geq 100\,000$: Candidates
- $T \geq 10\,000\,000$: Number of queries
- $3 \leq k \leq 20$: Expected number of returned points
- Reasonable memory consumption (e.g. less than 2GB for the data structure)

The query time for a single brute force approach is in $\mathcal{O}(m \cdot n)$ as it just compares every candidate point in $D$ with the query and stores the closest $k$ of them.

### Misc

I've just implemented this with Python (see [code](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/unit-hypersphere-nn)).

- `k=5, n=128, m=100000, T=100: 0.56s per query.` (Brute force approach)

That is actually much better than I expected. However, I guess this could be an order of magnitude faster with a good data structure / smarter algorithm. I wrote the Python script in a way which should make it easy to run your own experiments on your tests, if you like.

Comment: Have you checked [KD Trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#kd-tree)?

Comment: @joanolo According to Wikipedia ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#High-dimensional_data)) they are not suited in my case as the dimensionality of the points is much too high.

Comment: Check [Ball tree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#ball-tree) then. (I've personally never used it, but I haven't been _cursed_ by dimensionality ;-) ...).

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, when the number of dimensions $n$ is less than about 10, fancy data structures (like k-d trees) work well; when the number of dimensions is greater than about 30, fancy data structures typically perform poorly and may be no better than a brute-force linear scan.  Wikipedia lists a [similar rule of thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree): if $m \gg 2^n$ (where $m$ is the number of points in the data structure and $n$ is the number of dimensions), then k-d trees work well, otherwise they won't.  Exceptions exist, e.g., where your data is "structured" and non-random, but this is probably a good first guideline.

In your example, the number of dimensions is at least 100.  Therefore, I wouldn't expect any of the fancy data structures (k-d trees, M-trees, etc.) to be better than the simple linear scan.

Essentially, you are suffering from the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

You mention that your points are all on the surface of the hypersphere.  Unfortunately, this doesn't help much.  Heuristically, points on the surface of a $n$-dimensional hypersphere are a lot like points in a $n-1$-dimensional space.

Comment: Additional explanation on the last part: points on circle are in bijection with points on a line plus one. Points on a 3-sphere are in bijection with points on a plane plus one. (Projection from a pole) And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Points of an high-dimensional metric space may efficiently be indexed by an M-tree. An in-depth discussion of the data structure and of your problem may be found in [this](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/research/papers/SEBD97.pdf) paper.

Comment: I think you should at least (1) give the name + authors of the paper directly, as the link might vanish (2) give the general idea of M-trees.